# isset() Returns false on file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple page that has a upload button, which I changed the name of to be "Upload" instead of "Choose file", I also just wanted to have one button, not "choose" file and a "submit" buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    background-color: #0fffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" />
</div>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo"file exists";
}
else {
    echo"file doesn't exist";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The line:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
```

Always returns false, I also tried:

Using `!empty()`
I have to use a form of `type="file"`, as I only want to have one button, the "Upload" button, which uploads and submits at the same time.

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Because u forgot to use name attribute

Comment: Adding name="file" to the form doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try inserting a print_r($_FILES) before the isset if condition, it will dump the full contents of $_FILES and help you see what it contains.

Comment: Have you submitted the form? It will show `false` when you first open the page, it should show `true` when you submit the form.

Comment: The page doesn't load anything once I try that.

Comment: Than how can u get the value of file???

Comment: I don't want to have a submit button (As I mentioned in my question), so how would I submit it in one go, without one.

Comment: You need to use Javascript to submit the form when the user changes the file input.

Comment: You forgot to add name param to input. Just add name = "file" and you will get what you need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Javascript to submit the form when the user selects a file.

And you need to give a name to the file input, to match the key in `$_FILES`.

```js
document.getElementById("file-upload").addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.form.submit();
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The javascript code has to go in it's own <script> </script> block?